# Helpers that are not horizontal or vertical

Tags: gimp

In Gimp, I can create helpers (those dashed lines) by pulling them out of the pixel scales at the sides.

Sometimes, it would be very much helpful if I was able to rotate those lines to make them not exactly horizontal or vertical but following eg. a perspective.

It that somehow possible? Or can I use anything else as a replacement?

Comment: [Gimp-forum says:](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Angled-Guides) "No, you can't. But you can have a **straight path at any angle** and use **View>Snap to active path** for something very similar"

Comment: You could make that into an answer as it perfectly answers my question and even gives a replacement. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gimp-forum says](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Angled-Guides):

> No, you can't. But you can have a **straight path at any angle** and
>   use **View>Snap to active path** for something very similar